# Android Kotlin ImageView binding

Tags: android, binding, kotlin

How do I bind data to an imageview in kotlin?

```
<ImageView               
    app:photoFilePath="@{item.photoFilePath}"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
/>
```

**This is my class what i have implemented :**

```
class OrderInfoFragment : BaseDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var mOrderItem: OrderItem
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val inflater = activity.layoutInflater
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentOrderInfoBinding>(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_order_info, null, false)
        val view = binding.root
          binding.item = mOrderItem
    }

    @BindingAdapter("bind:photoFilePath")
    fun loadPhotoFilePath(imageView: ImageView, path: String) {

    }
}
```

I have tried using `loadPhotoFilePath` in the companion object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function`loadPhotoFilePath` should be out of class, place it above `class OrderInfoFragment`.

Or another way would be to annotate it as `@JvmStatic`